# Self-requests appearing on an Apache SSL site

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have an SSL site running on Apache that seems to be recieving regular self-requests of some kind.  Is this something that Apache is doing?  What is the reason?

```
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:00 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 157
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:03 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 160
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:14 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 147
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:15 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 128
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:16 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 167
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:17 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 141
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:18 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 166
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:20 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 168
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:21 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 160
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:31 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 177
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:32 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 103
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:38 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 157
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:39 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 193
    (ip address) - - [23/Apr/2010:14:21:40 +1200] -:443 "GET /" 400 637 "-" "-" (-) 168
```

Comment: Does the home page reload via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache does some internal sub-requests sometimes for various module functions, including PHP applications.  I think PHP actually makes a call available for it. Now, I believe the logs are usually more detailed than that (see your error log?), but that's my assumption here.  A good example is mod_include, when loading data for an "include virtual" directive.